# Fragment already added exception with singleton dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, singleton

I have a progress dialog which is a singleton because I want it to be shown only once if it gets called multiple times, and doesn't stack on itself. but somewhere in my code, it gets called simultaneously from two places and I get fragment already added exception.

I'm checking if the dialog is not added to activity then I call Dialog.show() but since the method gets called simultaneously from two places, before the first one is added to activity the other one is passed throw if statement and that causes the problem.
I want two thread-safe the function so that multiple threads cant call it simultaneously.

as you can see I've tried synchronizing it by @Synchronized annotation but it didn't work

```
class ProgressDialogFragment private constructor() : DialogFragment() {

    companion object {

        private var dialogInstance: DialogFragment? = null

        @JvmStatic
        @Synchronized
        fun showDialog(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
            if (dialogInstance == null) {
                dialogInstance = ProgressDialogFragment().apply {
                    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Dialog_FullScreen)
                    isCancelable = false
                }
            }

            if (!dialogInstance!!.isAdded && fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("progress_dialog") == null) {
                dialogInstance!!.show(fragmentManager, "progress_dialog")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in the documentation, the `DialogFragment#show()`

> Display the dialog, adding the fragment to the given FragmentManager. This is a convenience for explicitly creating a transaction, adding the fragment to it with the given tag, and committing it.

`FragmentTransactions` commits are async, to make sure it is committed before you move on just call `executePendingTransactions()` :

```
 if (!dialogInstance!!.isAdded && fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("progress_dialog") == null) {
         dialogInstance!!.show(fragmentManager, "progress_dialog")
         fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
}
```

As for the `@Synchronized` it's unnecessary in this situation because this function can only run in the UI Thread.

Comment: thank you, this works. is this singleton pattern the best way to have just one dialog at a time?

Comment: The "best way" is something hard to grasp, but I can tell you that I wouldn't use singleton in this situation. The issue that you were facing only happened because you have at least two places responsible for notifying progress (I'm assuming that this is what ProgressDialog is for). I would go for isolating this responsibility to begin with. 

Singletons can be bad. You should use it abusively. Here is why: https://dzone.com/articles/singleton-anti-pattern